# Dynamic block titles

Tags: 7, blocks

I have added a custom block to my users' profile page that shows a list of all that user's submissions.  I would like the title to be the user's name then projects so for the user Mike I would like to see "Mike's Projects" as the block title.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is a good question, I know the easiest way is in a custom module, like Daniel said. It`s quite easy and is the usual way one would attack this, but I am curious as to if it can be done on php code through the block admin interface? , I assume one very ugly hack that would work would be simply using hook_block_view_alter with an existing module, thereby 'hijacking` the hook for that particular block. Example: function block_block_view_alter() would hijack the use of block`s hook. Still. Don`t do this. Good-luck

Comment: Would any of these help out-of-the-box (or provide a basis for writing your own)? : http://drupal.org/project/page_title  http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like to get dirty with PHP code than you can install [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module, hide the title (add `<none>` in the title field) and create your title in the content of the block wrapping it in a  tag. The new title would be like this: `<h2>[user:name]'s Projects</h2>`

Answer (score 7):

If you're familiar with Drupal's hook system, you can do this via [hook_block_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this thing with block.tpl.php in theme .$block->subject

```
if ($block->module=block && $block->delta='Your block ID' ){
print 'company name' }
else {print $block->subject;}
```

your block id ==click in config in block section in admin and you can have the block id in url at end