# How do I set a block title to the title of a referenced node?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

In Views 3, I have a block that is showing content from a particular Node ID. I'd like to have the title of that block set dynamically to what the referenced page's title is. I know this would be accomplished using Contextual Filters and that my display's title would be an argument, like %1 but I'm uncertain what the Contextual Filter settings should be. I'd rather not use PHP code if avoidable simply because I don't have the 'PHP Filter' module enabled on most sites I create.

Which settings should I use to make a block title the same as the title of a referenced node?

Answer (score 1):

In Views, with a block output & Content Entity Relationship set up, in 'Contextual Filters':

WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED
- Override title (tick this & I used %1 with some text)

which offers "Override the view and other argument titles. Use "%1" for the first argument, "%2" for the second, etc."

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the block title from within the view using contextual filters the way you are thinking, only the title of the view itself. On this page there is a similar goal and a few suggestions:

[Dynamic block titles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21362/dynamic-block-titles)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but maybe it can help someone. Just put on the view title `[title]`, and add the field title to field list in view; then, select *Exclude from display*. Done!

> [image: First add [title] and then include in fields]

> [image: then it works]

Comment: This is not dynamic. You have set it to be based from one particular node which is unchangeable. The idea is for the title to change based on the node that is being viewed. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Where do you see a new question? There aren't questions at all.